# How to combine a dataGridView1, bindingNavigator1 and a DataTable?

Tags: c#

On a Form i have a dataGridView1 and a bindingNavigator1. I use a DataTable to export the result of a query.
How to combine them all? Now i can get the bindingNavigator1 to work but then i do not have a datatable.
When i create a  DataTable the bindingNavigator1 isn't working anymore.

```
private void buttonQueryTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sqlQuery = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Settings.applicatiePad + Form_Main.QueryMap + "\\query_test.sql");
            try
            {
                sqlExecute.sqlAantal(sqlQuery);  //query uitvoeren

                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(sqlExecute.cmd);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                try
                {
                    da.Fill(ds);

                    //connect binding navigatorto the dataset
                    BindingSource bs;
                    bs = new BindingSource();
                    bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                    bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bs;
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;


                       DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];  //then the bindingNavigator1 isn't working anymore
                       dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                //    DataTable dt = ((DataView)bs.DataSource).Table;  // wrong cast?
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //write to log....
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //write to log....
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: They are already "combined"